# Windows App UET SDK in UWP app missing assembly

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-app-sdk, bing-ads-api

I've been trying to implement ads tracking with Windows App UET SDK, following the [official guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/guides/windows-app-uet-sdk)

I have a default C# UWP "Blank app, Packaged with Windows Application packaging project (WinUI 3 in Desktop)" in Visual Studio 22 with Microsoft.BingAds.UETSdk nuget packaged added, which refused to build with

> Microsoft.BingAds.UETSdk.winmd cannot be referenced. Referencing a Windows Metadata component directly when targeting .NET 5 or higher is not supported. For more information, see https://aka.ms/netsdk1130

error, which goes away after also adding Microsoft.Windows.CsWinRT package to the project as directed.

But then I become unable to reference UETSdk altogether

[image: error msg]
despite the assembly reference showing up in the solution explorer
[image: solution explorer]

assembly dependency is automatically added together with UETSdk package.

Tried both net6 and net5 frameworks, VS and pc restarts with no luck. UETSdk package is quite new so I couldn't find any relevant info about dealing with similar problems.
It only contains a bunch of winmd files for different platforms with no source code to look into.

Would be super delighted to learn there's a solution. Thank you.

Comment: Did my reply about using Windows App UET SDK help you?

Comment: ah, totally! sorry, missed your reply at first, thought noone would  give a response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows App UET SDK only supports C#/C++ UWP WinRT project, please use Windows App UET SDK in UWP project.

The project you created `Blank app, Packaged with Windows Application packaging project (WinUI 3 in Desktop)` is a WinUI3 project, and it is not supported.