integrate the (Universal Event Tracking) SDK into our UWP
We are currently trying to integrate the UET (Universal Event Tracking) SDK (Microsoft.BingAds.UETSdk) into our UWP product. We have been following the documentation closely, but we encounter an issue as soon as we implement the step "Import all of the .NET Native / CoreCLR props" from this guide. After adding this step, when we attempt to submit our UWP package to the Windows Store, we receive the error: "You cannot submit pre-compiled .NET Native packages."
For testing purposes, we created an entirely blank project and followed the instructions step by step:

Blank project (UetTestBlank.rar and UetTestBlank_1.0.60.0_x86_x64_arm_arm64) - successfully submitted to the Windows Store.
Added only the .dll without modifying project settings (UetTestUetPkgOnly_1.0.60.0_x86_x64_arm.appxbundle and UetTestUetPkgOnly.rar) - successfully submitted to the Windows Store.
Modified the project by adding "Import all of the .NET Native / CoreCLR props" (UetTestUetPkgWithProjectFileMod.rar and UetTestUetPkgWithProjectFileMod_1_0_60_0_x86_x64_arm_arm64_appxbundle) - submission failed with the error: UetTestUetPkgWithProjectFileMod_1_0_60_0_x86_x64_arm_arm64_appxbundle 3.2 MB, "Package acceptance validation error: You cannot submit pre-compiled .NET Native packages. Please upload the Microsoft Store appxupload file and try again."

You can find all the project files here: Dropbox link
Could there be any inaccuracies in the documentation, or does anyone have experience working with this library who could provide some guidance or examples?
Thank you!

Does this apply? "We currently support C# and C++11."

we tried C#, the same result.

That's the thing ... In C#, they "imply" you "publish first"; then add the SDK ... as if the SDK is something that gets bound "in / to / at the store" .

I don't quite understand you. Packages without the SDK are indeed accepted by the store just fine. As soon as we make modifications to the project according to their documentation... the Windows Store no longer wants to accept it.

There were no specific instructions for C#; only for C++. Anyway, there's this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77375191/windows-app-uet-sdk-in-uwp-app-missing-assembly

I saw this topic. His project didn't even compile. We have a completely different situation.
